# Java constructor calling another constructor

Tags: java, syntax, constructor, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I am new in Java and I am trying to call a constructor inside other constructor. Here is my code:

```
class TestContructor {
    public TestContructor(){
        String params = "1, 2, 3";
        this(params);
    }
    public TestContructor(String params){
        System.out.println("TestContructor with params: " + params);
    }
}

class TestRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestContructor();
    }
}
```

Then I got this error:

```
javac -g Test.java
Test.java:5: error: call to this must be first statement in constructor
        this(params);
            ^
1 error
```

And ok, I changed the TestConstructor code:

```
class TestContructor {
    public TestContructor(){
        // String params = "1, 2, 3";
        this("1, 2, 3"); //Now is the first statement
    }
    public TestContructor(String params){
        System.out.println("TestContructor with params: " + params);
    }
}
```

And Ok, no problems.

Then, is it a rule in java to call another constructor it must be declared in the first statement line?

What about if I need to do some kind of process before call the other constructor?

I recall I am newer in java programming, but I have this problem and I want to know if it is possible to do that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a rule.

If you need to do other work first, your only real option is to refactor that work into another method. Something like:

```
public TestConstructor(String params) {
    // whatever
}

public TestConstructor(String... paramParts) {
    this(combineParts(paramParts));
}

private static String combineParts(String[] parts) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String part : parts) {
        sb.append(part);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you have various computations that depend on one another (for instance, you need to call `this(foo, bar)` where `bar` depends on the answer to `foo` and some other component `baz`), then you can chain constructors even more. Something like:

```
public TestConstructor(FooComponent1 f1, FooComponent2 f2, Baz baz) {
    this(createFoo(f1, f2), baz);
}

private TestConstructor(Foo foo, Baz bar) {
    this(foo, createBar(baz));
}

private TestConstructor(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    // do whatever
}
```

Note that I've made the helper constructors private. This is particularly useful if `Bar` is a private inner class, so there's no way for an external caller to create one and pass it in.